# Not enough space to show ad with admob

Tags: android, admob

the logcat only gives one error, not enough space to show ad. Everything in the app works fine except for the admob ad on the launch screen. Here is the XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip"
    android:text="Exit"
    android:textSize="20.0dip" />

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="XXXXXX"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
 </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

All I want to have on the screen is a full page ad and a button that will close the add and launch the main activity when clicked. The button works fine but when that xml loads it does not show an ad and the window that opens is much smaller then the screen.

Here is the .Java activity that the above layout is set to.

```
package com.androidsleepmachine.gamble;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Splash extends Activity {

Button close;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close);
    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.Home");
            startActivity(i);


        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: why do you put the `AdView` in a `RelativeLayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set layout_height to wrap_content on the parent. Use this instead:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip"
    android:text="Exit"
    android:textSize="20.0dip" />

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="XXXXXX"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
 </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**
You need to use code in your activity to load your app, according to https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#android:

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

**EDIT 2:**

> As usual you must replace MY_AD_UNIT_ID with your AdMob publisher ID.
>   You must also add your own device ID in the ads:testDevices attribute
>   to get test ads on your device.

I was just assuming you were actually changing these values... yes you have to actually put values for these.

Comment: It still does not run. it opens a small box and the button in the box but nothing else.

Comment: Did you load the ad? As well as the xml part, you also need to do some code in the activity. The Admob dev guide has a tutorial

Comment: I was told, and have seen several examples, were the ad was just created in the XML, I dont have any code in the activity launching the ad

Comment: I copied your XML code exactly, and I put your AdView code in my activity inside the oncreate and it still only loads a small box in the middle of the screen with the exit button in it

Comment: I did change the XXXXXX with my admob ID. I currently am only running it on the emulator so I didnt change anything else

Comment: You still need to add it as a test device, the id should show in the logcat

Comment: test_emulator is not good enough? I am new to all of this, first experience with admob so I know most of this stuff is stupid mistakes i keep making.

Comment: No the guide I linked shows how to get the proper test id, it's in the log. Yeah I remember when I first did admob, the key is to not try to cut corners, they'll always come back to bite you...

Comment: @user2727048 Can you post a screenshot of what it looks like? This definitely should be working

Comment: http://imgur.com/k4V1fPw    That is a link to the screenshot I posted on imgur. It is on the emulator, the device looks the exact same as well.

Comment: It is because you are styling the activity as a dialog, does it work if you use a regular activity?

Comment: I dont understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: Your activity doesn't fill up the whole screen (it is a dialog). Dialog's can't have ads, only activities that fill the whole screen.

Comment: I have a .java class that when it loads it is set to the layout I have posted above.

Comment: Yes, but you have styled your activity as a dialog, this is most likely found in the manifest

Comment: You sir, are a genius. I copied and pasted in the manifest to add the .Slash activity and i copied the part that loads a dialog. I did not have any idea what I copied so I had no clue on where to start to fix the issue. I deleted  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"  ouf of the manifest and it works great. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Simply set the margins to **0dp** in **res->values->dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
```